# Exception in spring boot auto configuration

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When i startup spring boot application exception occurred in auto configuration.the response when i implement spring data JPA is given below

**The error is**

description:

Field repositoryObject in com.umn.documentfetching.documentcatching.DocumentLoader required a bean of type 'com.umn.documentfetching.repositorydata.DocumentLoaderRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.umn.documentfetching.repositorydata.DocumentLoaderRepository' in your configuration.

**main**

```
package com.umn.documentfetching;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.umn.documentfetching.entity.User;
import com.umn.documentfetching.repository.UserRepository;
import com.umn.documentfetching.service.dbUpdation;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DocumentFetchingWithHibernateApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private dbUpdation dbUpdationObject;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DocumentFetchingWithHibernateApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        User ob = new User();
        ob.setEmail("ranjithayarotta@gmail.com");
        ob.setId(1);
        ob.setName("ranjith");
        dbUpdationObject.inserdataintoDb(ob);


    }
}
```

**dao class**

```
package com.umn.documentfetching.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


}
```

**Repository class**

```
package com.umn.documentfetching.repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.umn.documentfetching.entity.User;



@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

**service class**

```
package com.umn.documentfetching.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.umn.documentfetching.entity.User;
import com.umn.documentfetching.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class dbUpdation {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepoObect;

    public void inserdataintoDb(User userData) {
        userRepoObect.save(userData);
    }

}
```

**This my properties file**

```
server.port=9891
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Documentloader
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=careernow@123
```

**This my pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>DocumentFetching</groupId>
    <artifactId>documentFetchingWithHibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>documentFetchingWithHibernate</name>
    <description>Load document store into the redis</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>


            `
```

Comment: did you try changing CrudRepository to JpaRepository

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars of different versions (2.0.1 and 2.0.3) and don't auto wire the field in the actual class that configures the application. That leads to eager instantiation of the object and will not auto wire everything.

Answer (score 0):

Change Long to Integer as below and try.

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just copied all your classes in my project and run it. It works perefectly.

## From my DB

[image: table1]

[image: table2]

The error says it all. You need to define `DocumentLoaderRepository`.